# Find Org expiration date

Tags: licenses, enterprise

How to find the expiration date of an org in salesforce.com

I tried this query:

```
Select TrialExpirationDate from Organisation
```

but it is returning null as the org is purchased one.

So, how can we find the expiration date of a purchased org?

Answer (score 5):

TrialExpirationDate tell us the date on which ***Trial*** is going to expire.

IF you have normal Dev org or purchases org then this field will be NULL

From the doc:

> Description:
>   The date that this organization's trial license expires.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm

I think if you want to find the expiration date purchases org then you need contact to SFDC support.

Comment: Or your account executive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Select TrialExpirationDate from Organization

Note:

1.At above shared query, Organization is misspelled.

2.User must have the “View All Data” permission to access this object.